# Calling a nested function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures, nested-function

I am new to JavaScript. I have this piece of code. I need to print the following:

```
//counter() should return the next number.
//counter.set(value) should set the counter to value.
//counter.decrease() should decrease the counter by 1

function makeCounter() {
  let count = 0;

  function counter() {
    return count++;
  }

  counter.decrease = function () {
    return count--;
  };

  counter.set = function (value) {
    return count = value;
  };
}
```

How can I call the 3 nested functions outside?

Comment: You cannot use `counter` outside if it's not exposed. Are you supposed to *change* this code? Or what should be done here?

Comment: I'd say you have to change this code. But I'm not sure. What is the guidance given to you for the task? You can either remove `makeCounter` or you can `return counter` from inside. Yet it might be neither. Hence my questions to you - are you supposed to change the code? Or what should be done here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to return your `counter`.

```js
function makeCounter() {
  let count = 0;

  function counter() {
    return count++;
  }

  counter.decrease = function () {
    return count--;
  };

  counter.set = function (value) {
    return count = value;
  };
  
  return counter;
}

const myCounter = makeCounter();

console.log(myCounter()); // 0
console.log(myCounter()); // 1
console.log(myCounter.set(42)); // 42
console.log(myCounter()); // 42 (*see why next)
console.log(myCounter.decrease()); // 43 (*see why next)
console.log(myCounter()); // 42
```

- Be carefull with notation `count++` because it returns `count` then add 1. If you want to add 1 then return the new value of `count`, please write `++count`.

Comment: Thanq. This is exactly what I needed.